# What is the maximal velocity of air blown through a straw?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, estimation, flow, bernoulli-equation

If an adult can buildup a pressure of 9kPa when blowing air through a straw then the pressure drop will be 0.5*1.25*v^2. But if I want to compute the air volocity in the straw how can I know the pressure in the other end of the straw as a function of its dimensions?

Comment: If you are on the surface of the Earth, then the pressure at the other end should be just 1 ATM.

Comment: @AaronStevens So if the pressure drop is 9kPa I get a velocity of 120 m/s. This can't be true.

Comment: Also if the pressure would be 1 ATM I guess the air speed at the end of the straw would be 0.

Comment: How are you getting 120 m/s? I am getting about 1/10 of that with my calculations.

Comment: @AaronStevens 0.5*1.25*v^2=9000 --> v=120 m/s.

Comment: Where are you getting the 1.25? Also, your calculations make no reference to the applied 9 kPa pressure nor the 1 atm pressure at the other end of the straw.

Comment: 1.25 is the air density, I assume that 9kPa is extra pressure relative to the 1 ATM so v^2=9000*2/1.25